# getchar() not accepting input

Tags: c, input

I am writing a program to implement a linked list in C.Here is my program.

```
/*Implementing a singly linked list in c*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<alloca.h>

   struct node{

    int data;
   struct node* link;
}*start=NULL;


void main(){

    char choice;
    int data;

    do{

        printf("Enter data\n");
        scanf("%d",&data);

        struct node* temp;
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=data;
        temp->link=NULL;

        if(start==NULL)
            start=temp;
        else
        {
            struct node* traversing_pointer;
            traversing_pointer=start;
            while(traversing_pointer!=NULL)
                traversing_pointer=traversing_pointer->link;

            traversing_pointer->link=temp;

        }
         printf("Do you want to enter more");
 choice=getchar();        

    }
    while(choice=='y'|| choice=='Y');}
```

I basically want at least one node in the linked list to be created, that is why I am using a do, while loop. But after the first data input the program terminates without accepting an input for `choice` variable. Here is my output. What can be the

```
Enter data
45
Do you want to enter more
RUN FINISHED; exit value 10; real time: 2s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

What can be the possible error?

Comment: We need a new `tag` in stackoverflow exclusively dedicated to this topic of `getchar() after scanf() sad situation`.

Comment: The value `10` is for `\n` (the newline character from you pressing 'Enter'). `scanf()` didn't consume it, so it's the next-available character in the buffer and `getchar()` picks it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To consume the newline character left in the input stream, do:

```
scanf("%d",&data);
getchar(); //To consume a newline
```

or use a loop to read all newlines.

```
scanf("%d",&data);
int c=0;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) ; // Read & ignore all newlines
```

Another problem I see is you are not linking the nodes properly. You want to link the new node as the last one. So you have to traverse till the last node (not till you reach NULL). Change the loop condition to:

```
while(traversing_pointer->link!=NULL)
    traversing_pointer=traversing_pointer->link;

traversing_pointer->link=temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your `getchar` reads the end of line you've entered by pressing Enter after the `45` input.

Comment: Use another `getchar` :)

Comment: I simply put a 'getchar()` between the `printf()` statement and the `choice=getchar()` statement. It runs fine for one step but then gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: That's another of your problems and it's outside the scope of this question.